# Is it possible to add a title to the inputfield

Tags: inputfield

I was wondering if it is possible to add a title to

```
InputField
```

As far as I know, you can only add a FieldHint, this one will disappear however as soon as the user has entered input. But I still want the user to know what his input corresponds to. So I was wondering if there is some sort of a workaround for that.

Edit: Tried to implement it but it shows up with {}, which is not what I want, could it be that the problem is that I use Column, instead of Grid? Documentation would suggest otherwise...

```
Panel[Column[{{"Purchase Price", 
InputField[Dynamic[purchaseprice], Number, 
 FieldHint -> "Purchase Price", 
 ImageMargins -> 10]}, {"Equity Capital", 
InputField[Dynamic[EK], Number, FieldHint -> "Equity capital", 
 ImageMargins -> 10]}, {"Mortgage rate in %", 
InputField[Dynamic[mortgagerate], Number, 
 FieldHint -> "Mortgage Rate in %", 
 ImageMargins -> 10]}, {"Supplementary Costs per annum", 
InputField[Dynamic[supplymentary], Number, 
 FieldHint -> "Supplementary costs per annum", 
 ImageMargins -> 10]}, {"Payback Period", 
InputField[Dynamic[paybackperiod], Number, 
 FieldHint -> "Payback Period", 
 ImageMargins -> 10]}, {"Gross Income per annum", 
InputField[Dynamic[grossincome], Number, 
 FieldHint -> "Gross Income per annum", 
 ImageMargins -> 10]}, {"Calculatory mortgage rate", 
InputField[Dynamic[calcrate], Number, 
 FieldHint -> "Calculatory mortgage rate", ImageMargins -> 10]}, 
Dynamic@If[
 grossincome*0.33 > (purchaseprice - EK)*mortgagerate/100 + 
   supplymentary + 
   Max[{((purchaseprice - EK) - 0.66*purchaseprice)/paybackperiod,
      0}], TextCell[
  "Congratulation you are qualified for a mortgage", "Subtitle"], 
 Dynamic[Text["You only have "] Text[
    Round[((purchaseprice - EK)*mortgagerate/100 + supplymentary +
           Max[{((purchaseprice - EK) - 0.66*purchaseprice)/
             paybackperiod, 0}])/purchaseprice*100] Text[
      "% instead of 33%"]]]]}, 
Background -> 
Dynamic@If[
 grossincome*0.33 > (purchaseprice - EK)*mortgagerate/100 + 
   supplymentary + 
   Max[{((purchaseprice - EK) - 0.66*purchaseprice)/paybackperiod,
      0}], Green, Red]]]
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context about how you are using InputField?

Comment: Hope this helps

Comment: You have two options: (1) use `Column` like you did now, then each `{"label", inputfield}` needs to be wrapped in a `Row`. (2) You use `Column` like you did, but you use a `Grid` for your inputs like `Grid[{{"label 1", input1}, {"label 2", input2},..}]`.

Comment: Looks like you have an extra set of `{}` in your code.  Try removing the curly brackets around each row.  You might want to then adjust the text and alignment, but that works on my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to learn to help yourself. You know that `Manipulate` provides an easy way to have labels on controls. So the first step you take is to look how something like this is represented

```
Control[{{u, 1, "Label"}, 0, 2}]
```

Go to the output slider with the cursor and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to see its box-form. There, you will notice that it uses a simple `Grid` to attach the label to the control. That can be used with your `InputField` as well

```
Panel[
 Grid[{{"My Label", InputField[x]}}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Tried to implement your suggestion much appreciated, didnt know that you can see the box-form with this combination! However I did encounter some problems